# Xmouse controlling zoom in Photoshop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, adobe-photoshop, scrolling, xmouse

I have a Logitech MX Master mouse, and I've installed [X-Mouse](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to customize my buttons more than Logitech offers in their software.

In Photoshop you can zoom in/out by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> and srolling the mouse wheel.  I'd like to assign a macro for this to the secondary thumb/tilt wheel.  I scroll that wheel up and it sends the commands for <kbd>alt</kbd>+wheel up, and the opposite of course for the other direction.  I've set this but it does not seem to do what I want.

[image: X-Mouse Photoshop Settings not working]

In fact, with those settings the thumb/tilt wheel continues to scroll documents horizontally in Photoshop. Even if I change the thumb/tilt wheel to behave like the normal scroll wheel

[image]

or press other keyboard buttons like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> these actions do not work for Photoshop!

[image: X-Mouse settings for Ctrl++ and Ctrl+-]

Both of these configs just result in no change in Photoshop, the thumb/tilt wheel continues to behave as a horizontal scroll wheel.

Why is this and how can I fix this?  You'll notice I also have the middle button configured to press the spacebar and the left mouse button (so I can pan around in Photoshop with the hand tool), and this works just fine.  X-Mouse does work for Photoshop, but just not for these specific actions I am wanting!

Comment: It's not a tilt wheel, it's  completely different wheel. The MX range of mice are notoriously poor at working with 3rd party drivers. You could do this easily in Logi Options; alternatively you need a 3rd party driver that recognises the second wheel. [… or in this case, tbh, just use the keyboard's alt + regular wheel. It's hardly worth the effort to waste an entire wheel for this.] The next 'fun' will be that one click of the MX wheel will make the zoom jump too far first time, then settle after that ;)

Comment: It's just labeled "tilt wheel" in X-mouse.  When mouse buttons are clicked or wheels rolled X-Mouse will highlight which one is which, and these are highlighted when I scroll this wheel.  I know I have the correct area targeted.  No, the Logi options only allow me to assign key combos, I cannot combine keys with scroll wheels in the Logi options

Comment: Well… it's not a tilt wheel, whatever your control panel thinks it is - it's a 'continuous encoder' .. a wheel. BTW, you can't use two drivers at once; they fight.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, modifier tags can be combined like <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd> that applies to the next key only. However, if you assign non-key combinations with modifier keys should use this template in XMBC.

```
{PRESS}{ALT}{MWUP}{WAITMS:100}{RELEASE}{ALT}
```

Which basically `Press` and holds `Alt` before releasing it 100 ms later.

Some fields are directly modified by Logi Options agent app and XMBC cannot override them. You can check this by changing or disabling the default tilt wheels from XMBC. However, you can use your simulated keys in green areas in Photoshop.

[image: screenshot from Photoshop]

Not **Logi Options** but **Logi Options+** has a feature for Photoshop Zoom in predefined apps, which basically returns Alt+Vertical Wheel. With this option, you can use Zoom in every area of the Photoshop window.
[image: screenshot from LogiOptions+]

Comment: Well, this is odd because my Logi Options+ does not have that option for Photoshop! https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi3Cq.png

Comment: @FiniteLooper, is your Logi Options+ Firmware version 22.0.3?

Comment: The Logi+ Options software is at version 1.38.397153 which says it's the latest [according to their website](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500005516462).  My MX Master mouse's firmware is at 11.4.17, and the updater software won't see the mouse to update it any further.

Comment: Maybe you can message to customer support from right bottom corner of https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us